# Human Mascot vs Animal Mascot for a website illustration and identity?

Tags: illustration

I am wondering if a animal mascot is "easier" to like for users rather than a human mascot/logo.

Thinking about it, it seems to me that websites seldom use a human mascot.
I was considering using a human face as "mascot" or online identity, but it feels too invasive somehow.
Does anyone know of a study that shows that people tend to prefer animal mascot?

Comment: +1 asking about thought in design (instead of "how do I use X feature in Photoshop")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good logo is one that is easily identifiable and visually conveys meaning quickly, often through group association. Unfortunately, when applied to the human form one often winds up with a stereotype. At its best it is benign, but even benign stereotypes are easily seen as racist. (see: Land O'Lakes; Aunt Jemima; Alfred E Neuman; Notre Dame football)

Animal forms rarely carry this burden.

Comment: By the way: there is a site I look at occasionally which appears to be completely earnest but which I find oddly hilarious: ( http://suicidefood.blogspot.com/ ). It is an interesting take on the use of animal mascots in the context of food products.

Comment: accidentally forgot the church of subgenius from the list? :-D

Comment: cut me some slack :)